# Integer pointer array sorting in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a global integer pointer array, which is created this way

```
int * array;
array = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

I also have a sorting algorithm, which is supposed to sort 4 first numbers of the array which size is larger than 4 (16 in this case). sizeOfArray is defined as 4 in this case:

```
int temp,i,j;
for(i=0;i<sizeOfArray;i++){
    for(j=i;j<sizeOfArray;j++){
        if(array[i] > array[j]){
            temp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is really weird for some reason:

```
Unsorted: 7,6,9,3
Sorted:  3,6,5,1
```

The weirdest part is if I change algorithm to sort numbers in a descending order, it seems to work:

```
if(array[i] < array[j])

Unsorted: 10,0,1,8
Sorted: 10,8,1,0
```

What's causing this? I'm completely lost.

Comment: sizeof does not do what you intend, you need `size` as a loop condition.

Comment: does `size` and `sizeOfArray` have same values?

Comment: @kajacx No. `size` is 16, `sizeOfArray` is 4. My goal is to sort 4 first values of the array with 16 values. I'll update the question

Comment: Can you post compilable code that replicates the problem?

Comment: Put a printf() in the code and you'll see.

Comment: Since it has not been said yet, in C [cast shouldn't be used for *malloc*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc), just do: `array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code wrapped to make an MCVE [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void print(int n, int a[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%2d", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int size = 16;
    int *array = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    array[0] = 7;
    array[1] = 6;
    array[2] = 9;
    array[3] = 3;
    int sizeOfArray = 4;

    printf("Before:");
    print(sizeOfArray, array);

    int temp, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < sizeOfArray; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("After: ");
    print(sizeOfArray, array);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
Before: 7 6 9 3
After:  3 6 7 9
```

Since this is not the same as the output you get, there must be a difference — a crucial difference.  Since you don't show the code that initializes the array, nor show the code that demonstrates that the first 4 elements have the unsorted values, nor show the code that demonstrates the sorted values are wonky, it is not possible to say for certain what is wrong — but the problem is not in the code you show.

I've not fixed the code to check that the memory allocation succeeds; nor have I modified the code to release the allocated space.  Both should be done.

The code does use C99 features; it is trivial to revise it not to do so:

```
static void print(int n, int *a)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

and move the definition of `sizeOfArray` before the assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some iterations of your code with the values you provide : `7,6,9,3`. Also, let's assume that `sizeOfArray = 4`.
For `i = j`, your condition will never be executed, because `array[i] = array[j]`.

For `i = 0` and `j = 1` => `7 > 6` => `array = {6, 7, 9, 3}`
For `i = 0` and `j = 2` => `6 < 9` => `array = {6, 7, 9, 3}`
For `i = 0` and `j = 3` => `6 > 3` => `array = {3, 7, 9, 6}`

For `i = 1` and `j = 2` => `7 < 9` => `array = {3, 7, 9, 6}`
For `i = 1` and `j = 3` => `7 > 6` => `array = {3, 6, 9, 7}`

For `i = 2` and `j = 3` => `9 > 7` => `array = {3, 6, 7, 9}`

Thus, I obtained the four first elements of your array sorted correctly (which contains `size` elements and I assume that `size = 16`).

If you're not sure about the value of `sizeOfArray` or `size`, I suggest you to print them and to check if it's really the value you want.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually, this is not bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this  will work for your sorting array...in 2nd iteration sizeofarray-1 will work for loop j...

```
int temp,i,j;
for(i=0;i<sizeOfArray;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<sizeOfArray-1;j++)
    {
        if(array[i] > array[j])
        {
            temp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```